Microsoft ADK 10.1.26100.1, new Certificate, and Black Lotus
When using the latest ADK (10.1.26100.1) that has the Security Update for the Black Lotus Vulnerability, when I created a WinPE image I noticed that the image still has the Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011 Certificate signed. Where did I make a mistake in understanding? I thought that the image was going to have the new certificate of Windows UEFI CA 2023, or is it going to be able to under go the changes using bcdboot.exe to then have the latest certificate as outlined in the KB article?
What I have tested:
I made the WinPE using the ADK and simply changed the WinPE bootx64.efi in the EFI\Boot\ directory with one that has the Windows UEFI CA 2023 Certificate.
I was thinking BCDBOOT would do this, because I copied the same command that was on the KB Article. However, when testing it kept throwing an error saying that bcdboot.exe does not have a /bootex flag. Would this be because of the PowerShell Version, or the bcdboot.exe version.

Microsoft still expects you to install Windows UEFI CA 2023.  We have not yet reached that step in their deployment plan where it's already been done. I originally thought the certificate had been pushed to the images, your last question proved to me, that is not the case. That likely won't happen until the shortly before the Enforcement Phase.

@Ramhound How about /bootex not being a flag in the bcdboot.exe in my computer?

It should work.  I have no idea if it should work in PowerShell as bootbcd is typically called through a Command Prompt.  This if you want to believe the response, "installs the bootloader files on the system partition, allowing the operating system to start.". Seems uncessary if the  correct certificate is already installed.

@EnlightenedFunky, that sounds like you're running an outdated version of Windows that doesn't ship the new-signed bootloader.

@grawity - Microsoft's own documentation on bcdboot makes no mention of /bootex so I am wondering if bcdboot changed in 2023.

The option definitely exists in Windows 11, but is also mentioned in bcdboot /help of Windows 10 22H2 with the latest updates applied (the Win10 PC I just checked has bcdboot.exe 10.0.19041.4957, date modified 2024-10-13, and also has the new-signed boot files in C:\Windows\Boot\*_EX).

This command runs fine with /bootex in the command prompt.
It might throw error in powershell or Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
